# How to access ForeignKey-Objects in Django

Tags: python, django

Every user in my Django project has a list of Reports. I now want to display the user his list of reports. But how can I get all receipts which belong to a specific user?

**Report-Model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    workshop = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    hours = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False, default=4)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=False)
```

Comment: Are Receipts and Reports same class or different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if you want to get the reports of the logged in user you can do the following.

```
reports = Report.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

this should return all the reports of a user. Similarly change the `request.user` object to another user object and is should work fine as well.

Note - I am assuming "reports" and "receipts" are the same the thing here cause there's no mention of receipt attribute in your model.

Comment: I think you want `Report.objects.filter` as `get` must return only one object.

Comment: You're right, get may return more than one item I need filter here, thanks for the heads up.